# Prolog find all positions in a list of the minimum element

Tags: list, prolog

everyone!
I'am having some problems with finding all the occurence positions of the minimum element in a list.

My source code is like this:

**

```
findPos([], _, []).
findPos([_],_,[1]).
findPos([H1|Tail], Pos, [Pos|Ta]):-
% "Pos" is the current position in the list 
       findMin([H1|Tail], V),
       V=[H1],
       Pos2 is Pos+1,
       findPos([Tail], Pos2, [Ta]).

findPos([H1|Tail], Pos, [Ta]):-
       findMin([H1|Tail], V),
       not(V=[H1]),
       Pos2 is Pos+1,
       findPos([Tail], Pos2, [Ta]).**
```

where, ***findMin*** receives as first argument a list and returns using the second parameter, the minimum element of that list. 
The problem is that, every input list I would give(except the void one for which the answer is []), the answer is always 1 ... and I can't see what I am missing.. Any answer would be appreciated :D Thank you!

Comment: please indent your code properly.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new in this -stack overflow- thing... :D.

Comment: You could use a combination of `msort/2`, `nth1/3` and `findall/3`. Three steps and you have your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Note that your program each time *recalculates the minimum of the **remaining** list;* therefore a list with `[1,7,1,2,3]` will see `[1,1,2,3]` as the list of "minima". Furthermore this process is rather expensive.

Another aspect is that you make some syntax errors with respect to the syntactical sugar of lists which will result in errors.

A solution is - which is common in computer science - to separate concerns. I propose that `findPos` will only aim to find the indices of a given item. Such `findPos/3` predicate could look like:

```
findPos(X,L,Is) :-
    findPos(0,X,L,Is).

findPos(_,_,[],[]).
findPos(I,X,[Y|T],MIT) :-
    (X == Y -> MIT = [I|IT];MIT=IT),
    I1 is I+1,
    findPos(I1,X,T,IT).
```

The predicate uses an accumulator `I` that keeps track of the index, and each time increments the index.

Now you need to make a predicate that finds the indices of the minimum elements:

```
findMinPos(L,Is) :-
    findMin(L,M),
    findPos(M,L,Is).
```

Comment: `findPos/4` is not steadfast! The goal `findPos(a,[a],[])` succeeds; it should fail!

Comment: @repeat: better? Although I agree indeed it is better to write good predicates, I think it is sometimes more important that beginners understand how Prolog work without putting much stress on the design of a program (*i.e. design patterns are also scheduled after people have obtained a basic level of Java*). Furthermore I definitely admit that I didn't (aim to) obtain a high level of expertise in Prolog.